# JXBrowser modify cookies

Tags: cookies, jxbrowser

I have come across the https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013108-network-events in the JXBrowser and wanted to add new cookies so that it could be used in the subsequent calls.
The support is available to add headers however since no direct access is available for the cookies I tried using the

```
 public void onBeforeSendHeaders(BeforeSendHeadersParams paramBeforeSendHeadersParams)
  {
List<Cookie> cookieList = browser.getCookieStorage().getAllCookies();

}
```

Also note that the calls of below snippet produces the same exception

```
browser.getURL(); //Exception is thrown here

CookieStorage storage = setCookies(paramBeforeSendHeadersParams, browser, list);
storage.save();// Exceptino is thrown here
```

but if i do this i get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are trying to execute some code that invokes synchronous message send to IPC channel. This code is executed in the scope of the handler which is bounded to synchronous message received from IPC channel. Such code execution causes a deadlock in native code with high probability and is forbidden.

What is the reasoning behind this any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want your application to share cookies between several Browser instances.
It is possible to make Two Browser instances with the same BrowserContext instances which use the same user data directory. As a result, they will share cookies and cache files. For example:

```
BrowserContext context = new BrowserContext(
new BrowserContextParams("C:\\my-data1"));
Browser browser1 = new Browser(context);
Browser browser2 = new Browser(context);
```

In this case, you should not receive the exception.

Comment: This is referring to the JxBrowser 6 API and is no longer valid for JxBrowser 7.